# I can't implement checking function, checking function is returning "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: string, numpy, tuples, typeerror, indices

```
def sel_models():
     data1 = load_data('gm_2020.npz') 
     data2 = load_data('gm_2021.npz') 
     qtty1 = data1['qnts']
     qtty2 = data2['qnts']
     dcng1 = data1['models']
     dcng2 = data2['models']
     mask20 = (dcng1 == 'Damas') | (dcng1 == 'Cobalt') | (dcng1 == 'Nexia') | (dcng1 == 'Gentra')
     mask21 = (dcng2 == 'Damas') | (dcng2 == 'Cobalt') | (dcng2 == 'Nexia') | (dcng2 == 'Gentra')
     return qtty1[mask20], qtty2[mask21]`
```

I can't implement checking function, checking function is returning "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: show the full error, with traceback.

Comment: What is `load_data`?  It's not standard numpy.